# Net Core: Merge _Layout.cshtml with Kendo Telerik Client Side Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kendo-ui, telerik

I am trying to modify _Layout.cshtml to allow for Telerik Net Core UI. Need to add Client side resources to the page, By merging Layout with Telerik recommendations. Have been attempting for a long time, but not working. How would I conduct this properly? Looking for a final result page.

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/getting-started-copy-client-resources

Here is a Default Project Net Core

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication8</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">WebApplication8</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2019 - WebApplication8</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Telerik Recommends doing this, merging into the Layout Page:**

```
<head>
    ...

    <environment include="Development">
        ...

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.min.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        ...

        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-test-class="k-common-test-class"
            asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
            asp-fallback-test-class="k-theme-test-class"
            asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />
    </environment>

    <environment include="Development">
        ...

        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

        @* Place Kendo UI scripts after jQuery *@
        <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        ...

        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>

        @* Place Kendo UI scripts after jQuery *@
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.kendo">
        </script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']">
        </script>
    </environment>

    ...
</head>
```

**Final Result Page:?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That official website from Telerik does not seem to be working, try this:

https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-core-examples/blob/master/multiselect/get-post-data/SampleCoreApp/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SampleCoreApp</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.min.css" />

        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

        @* Place Kendo UI scripts after jQuery *@
        <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="k-common-test-class"
              asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.nova.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="k-theme-test-class"
              asp-fallback-test-property="opacity" asp-fallback-test-value="0" />

        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>

        @* Place Kendo UI scripts after jQuery *@
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.kendo">
        </script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']">
        </script>
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">SampleCoreApp</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018 - SampleCoreApp</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">

        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```